# Stack driver Google Cloud – Responded with SSL Handshake Error

Tags: ssl, monitoring, google-cloud-platform

I'm trying to configure uptime check monitoring for Google Cloud VM in Stackdriver. URL return valid output (in 2.3 seconds), but I get in Stackdriver error (after less than 2 seconds...) of:

> Responded with SSL Handshake Error in 60000 ms.

A load balancer is configured, but with the exact same configuration from another project in another region I can access.

Any ideas anyone?

[image]

[image]

Comment: I am getting the same error here... I have confirmed the server is up.  I have existing uptime checks with the exact same configurations, however, new checks cannot be created / tested.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issues as well. I played around by putting Protocol to TCP on port 443, seems like its successful. Not sure if this is the same with HTTPS check

Comment: While your answer may well be correct, it just *seems* to be a little bit vague... maybe consider editing your answer with a few more details (if possible)

Answer (score 0):

I know its a bit late, but I just want to give other ones a hint...

I also have the problem and I am still not able to resolve it, BUT!
I found a way to get the exact error message!

You need to go into the "Logging"-Section of the Google-Cloud-Console.
Then open the logs explorer.
Insert the following query:

`resource.type="uptime_url" severity=NOTICE resource.labels.host="<your hostname here>"`

After that choose on of the log entries and unfold them to find `google.monitoring.v3.UptimeCheckResult` with the result of the check and the error message

[image: Example of my error message]